# Angular 4 Mapbox create multiple maps by ngFor

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to create multiple maps using `*ngFor`, but inside the component div id must be ready before I assign it to mapbox's container variable. Unfortunately, if not used setTimeout, it throws error that map id is not defined.

My components html looks like this -

`<div class="css-map-custom" id="map{{mv_mapId}}"></div>`

And corresponding typescript is -

```
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: `map${this.mv_mapId}`, .....
```

And because of "div id not found" error, I've to put the map render function inside ngOnInit with setTimeout :(

Any lead regarding how to fix it in a more elegant manner?

Comment: Have you tried using ngAfterViewInit instead of the ngOnInit?

Comment: Thanks man! It worked :)

Comment: Happy to hear it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the DOM on "page load", you should use ngAfterViewInit instead of ngOnInit.

In a nutshell, this is the order of events:

constructor > ... ngOninit > ... template creation > ... ngAfterViewInit

[Here is more info on the official docs on lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).